# How ought I run the annotate function in gui-debugger/annotator on a datum?

Tags: syntax, macros, racket

I am trying to learn how to use the DrRacket debugger's `annotate` function.  My ultimate aim is to build a REPL that you can execute from within a closure and have access to everything that's in scope.  (see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876940/how-do-i-open-a-racket-repl-with-the-current-scope) on that topic and Greg Hendershott's well-researched [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19885984/585977))  For the time being, I'm just trying to explore how the annotate function works.  You can see my first exploratory attempt at using it, and the results, [here](http://pasterack.org/pastes/89).

The error, which is happing inside of the annotator, seems to arise when it tries to match he application of string-append.  The matcher is looking for a `#%plain-app` and the expanded syntax I'm presenting to it contains an `#%app`.  I'm unsure if I should be expanding the syntax differently so it comes out as a `#%plain-app` or if there's something else I'm doing wrong to produce the syntax I'm feeding into the annotator.  Does anybody see where my error is?

Comment: Maybe something like `local-expand` instead of `expand` is part of the answer? But at this stage, probably you should ask on the Racket mailing list. That way, someone like Robby Findler (who I think wrote `annotate` as well as most of DrRacket) could respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This revision](http://pasterack.org/pastes/3915) to my previous pasterack post is swallowed without complaint. It seems that the syntax match must take place on a top-level syntax object (ruling out anything that could happen in an expansion phase, like a macro), and expansion must take place with a current namespace attached.  There are some more subtleties in the syntax match, particularly around the fact that the syntax object needs to be free-identifier=? to #%plain-app.  For all the gory details, refer to the [mailing list thread I started](http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2014-January/061060.html).